# Do I need to manually enter in gcode to turn off the bed and nozzle?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I got into 3D printing back when it was very much an art and not user friendly, and I have not been keeping up with it very much.  My Slic3r profile required me to manually put in the GCODE to turn off the nozzle and bed.  I'm experimenting with Cura and I can't seem to find a place to enter in GCODE.  The program is way more polished than I am used to, so it's possible that it's an automatically enabled feature.

Does Cura automatically turn off the bed and nozzle after a print is complete, or do I need to manually enter the GCODE somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Using Cura 3.0.3 to create the GCODE and OctoPi/OctoPrint 1.2.7 to print: By default the printer turned off the nozzle and bed, and also homed the X and Y axises.

You can set start and end GCODE in the preferences for the machine, like so:

[image]